How to Download a Large File from a URL and Upload It to Salesforce as a Static Resource?
I am working on a process where I need to programmatically download a .gz file from a public URL (https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.ratings.tsv.gz) and upload it to Salesforce as a Static Resource. The file is quite large (greater than 6 MB,250 MB), and I’m encountering challenges because Salesforce imposes limits on HTTP response size (6 MB).
My main goal is to:
Download the .gz file using an HTTP GET request.
Decompress the .gz file in Apex.
Either save the decompressed file back to Salesforce as a Static Resource or store the file's content elsewhere in Salesforce (e.g., Files or Attachments).
I tried making an HTTP callout using Apex, but I ran into the size limit. I am now considering options like splitting the file, using external services (e.g., Java Spring Boot), or chunking the data but I prefer a solution in Salesforce domain. What is the best way to handle this scenario while adhering to Salesforce limits? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

If you want to do it in Apex, I imagine you'll need to look in to HTTP multipart.
